# unable to install discovery service in linux

Tags: web8

We ran discovery service in Linux however it is not accessing. We have executed below commands in Linux and below is output.

```
curl http://xx.xx.x.xx:8082/discovery.svc
curl: (7) Failed to connect to xx.xx.x.xx port 8082: Connection refused



sudo sh start.sh
The service already started.
To start service again, run stop.sh first.



ps -ef | grep disc
root       956     1  3 12:10 pts/0    00:00:36 java -cp services/discovery-service:services/discovery-service/*:services/odata-v4-framework:services/odata-v4-framework/*:services:services/*:.:config:bin:lib/* -Xrs -Xms128m -Xmx128m com.sdl.delivery.service.ServiceContainer

PS C:\Windows\system32> Add-TtmCdEnvironment -Id Staging_Environment
cmdlet Add-TtmCdEnvironment at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
(Type !? for Help.)
DiscoveryEndpointUrl: http://xx.xx.x.xx:8082/discovery.svc
EnvironmentPurpose: Staging
Add-TtmCdEnvironment : Unable to save item of type 'CdEnvironmentData' with id 'Staging_Environment'.
One or more errors occurred.
An error occurred while communicating with CD Discovery Service 'http://xx.xx.x.xx:8082/discovery.svc' in CD Environment 
'Staging_Environment'. 
Unable to connect to the remote server
Unable to connect to the remote server
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established 
connection failed because connected host has failed to respond xx.xx.x.xx:8082
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-TtmCdEnvironment -Id Staging_Environment
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Tridion.Topolog...ironmentCommand:AddCdEnvironmentCommand) [Add-TtmCdEnvironment],  
   DataServiceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Tridion.TopologyManager.Automation.AddCdEnvironmentCommand
```

when we redirected in apache now it is getting below response

```
Add-TtmCdEnvironment : Unable to save item of type 'CdEnvironmentData' with id 'Staging_Environment'.
One or more errors occurred.
An error occurred while communicating with CD Discovery Service 'http://xx.xx.x.xx:8082/discovery.svc' in CD Environment 
'Staging_Environment'. 
An error occurred while processing this request.
The response payload is a not a valid response payload. Please make sure that the top level element is a valid Atom or JSON 
element or belongs to 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/data' namespace.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-TtmCdEnvironment -Id Staging_Environment
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Tridion.Topolog...ironmentCommand:AddCdEnvironmentCommand) [Add-TtmCdEnvironment],  
   DataServiceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Tridion.TopologyManager.Automation.AddCdEnvironmentCommand
```

could you please let us know if we miss any configuration

Thanks in Advance

Comment: A firewall maybe? How sure are you of the port being used? Use netstat to figure out which port this process is listening on, something like shown here http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-process-has-open-linux-port/

Comment: I got below response ubuntu@:/applications/java/discovery/config$ netstat -tulpn | grep :8082
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1000 but you should be root.)

Comment: "but you should be root" --> basically, you don't have permissions to check this. I assume there is someone around that has this type of access and can help you?

Comment: we ran command with bash and it is started sudo bash start.sh and we ran this command                 ubuntu@:~$ sudo netstat -pl | grep 5651
tcp6       0      0 [::]:8082               [::]:*                  LISTEN      5651/java
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     210998   5651/java           /tmp/.java_pid5651.tmp

Comment: we are unable to accessing it from browser or command prompt , please check edited question.